# Schmidt Measure of a Graph State

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, quantum-computing

Based on the definition of the Schmidt measure in this work https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/quant-ph/0307130/, the following code was set up, but appears to
generate errors. Is there a better way to design the code to remove these errors.

```
(* Schmidt Measure of a  graph state *)

adjacencyMatrix = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0}};

g = AdjacencyGraph[adjacencyMatrix];

{VertexCount[g], EdgeCount[g]};

(*Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the adjacency matrix*)
{eigenvalues, eigenvectors} = Eigensystem[adjacencyMatrix]

(*Sort the eigenvalues in decreasing order and corresponding 
eigenvectors*)
{eigenvalues, eigenvectors} = 
 Reverse /@ SortBy[Transpose[{eigenvalues, eigenvectors}], First]

(*Compute the Schmidt measure by summing the squares of the absolute 
values of the entries in the first half of each eigenvector*)
schmidtMeasure = 
  Total[Map[#^2 &, 
    Abs[eigenvectors[[All, 1; Length[eigenvalues]/2]]], {2}]];

(*Print the result*)
Print["The Schmidt measure of the graph state is ", N[schmidtMeasure]]
```

(* Messy Output is obtained *)

Comment: To sort you need to sort by numeric values (the default is by canonical order). `SortBy[Transpose[{eigenvalues, eigenvectors}], N[First[#]] &]`

Answer (score 4):

I fixed some things in the code in order to produce the desired results written in your code comments:

1. As pointed out by Bob Hanlon you should sort by numeric values and use `N[First[#]] &` for sorting.
2. If you want to assign the sorted results to the  structure `{eigenvalues, eigenvectors}` you need to `Transpose` the sorted data again instead of using `Reverse/@` on the data.

   ```
    (*Sort the eigenvalues in decreasing order and corresponding eigenvectors*)
    {eigenvalues, eigenvectors} = SortBy[Transpose[{eigenvalues, eigenvectors}], N[First[#]] &] //Transpose
   ```
3. To specify a `Span` (`;;`) for selecting a range of elements you need two semicolons between the start and end index.
4. In this example you have 5 eigenvalues - so dividing the `Length` by two results in 5/2 which cannot be used as index. You need to decide if you want to round up or down to the next integer value. Using `Floor` rounds down, so you take 2 eigenvalues.
5. If you want to sum up all elements you need to specify this as an additional parameter in `Total` (add `2` as a second parameter).

   ```
    (*Compute the Schmidt measure by summing the squares of the absolute values of the entries in the first half of each eigenvector*)
    schmidtMeasure = Total[Map[#^2 &, Abs[eigenvectors[[All, 1 ;; Floor[Length[eigenvalues]/2]]]], {2}], 2];
    (*Print the result*)
    Print["The Schmidt measure of the graph state is ", N[schmidtMeasure]]
   ```